# Why does formik.handleChange convert the input type number to a number whereas event.target.value returns a string?

Tags: html, next.js, formik

In the following code the event.target.value returns a string:

```
        <input
          type='number'
          value={form.cancel}
          onChange={event => setFormValues('cancel', event.target.value)}
        />
```

whereas in the following code the onChange={formik.handleChange} sets the value to a number:

```
        <input
          name={`${i}.seats`}
          type='number'
          value={formik.values[i]?.seats}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
          onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
        />
```

I did not find anything in the formik documentation that helped me understand why this is the case.

Comment: The first case happens because you manually set the value to be a string (`event.target.value` **ALWAYS** returns a string), for the second case you let the library do what it should.